# need guidance with basic function creation in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, function, matrix

I have to write a MATLAB function with the following description:

function counts = letterStatistics(filename, allowedChar, N)

This function is supposed to open a text file specified by filename and read its entire contents. The contents will be parsed such that any character that isn’t in allowedChar is removed. Finally it will return a count of all N-symbol combinations in the parsed text. This function should be stored in a file name “letterStatistics.m” and I made a list of some commands and things of how the function should be organized according to my professors' lecture notes:

1. Begin the function by setting the default value of N to 1 in case:

a. The user specifies a 0 or negative value of N.

b. The user doesn’t pass the argument N into the function, i.e.,  counts = letterStatistics(filename, allowedChar)

2. Using the fopen function, open the file filename for reading in text mode.
3. Using the function fscanf, read in all the contents of the opened file into a string variable.
4. I know there exists a MATLAB function to turn all letters in a string to lower case. Since my analysis will disregard case, I have to use this function on the string of text.
5. Parse this string variable as follows (use logical indexing or regular expressions – do not use for loops):

a. We want to remove all newline characters without this occurring:
e.g.
In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
In my younger and more vulnerableyears my father gave me some advicethat I’ve been turning over in my mindever since.

Replace all newline characters (special character \n) with a single space: ' '.

b. We will treat hyphenated words as two separate words, hence do the same for hyphens '-'.

c. Remove any character that is not in allowedChar. Hint: use regexprep with an empty string '' as an argument for replace.

d. Any sequence of two or more blank spaces should be replaced by a single blank space.

6. Use the provided permsRep function, to create a matrix of all possible N-symbol combinations of the symbols in allowedChar.
7. Using the strfind function, count all the N-symbol combinations in the parsed text into an array counts. Do not loop through each character in your parsed text as you would in a C program.
8. Close the opened file using fclose.

HERE IS MY QUESTION: so as you can see i have made this list of what the function is, what it should do, and using which commands (fclose etc.). the trouble is that I'm aware that closing the file involves use of 'fclose' but other than that I'm not sure how to execute #8. Same goes for the whole function creation. I have a vague idea of how to create a function using what commands but I'm unable to produce the actual code.. how should I begin? Any guidance/hints would seriously be appreciated because I'm having programmers' block and am unable to start!

Comment: Just use `fclose` as in the documentation, nothing tricky. Nobody is going to write your code for you, just start doing what you've written. Try `N=1;` to set the value of `N` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are new to matlab, so the documentation may be complicated. The root of the problem is the basic understanding of file I/O (input/output) I guess. So the thing is that when you open the file using `fopen`, matlab returns a pointer to that file, which is generally called a **file ID**. When you call `fclose` you want matlab to understand that you want to close that file. So what you have to do is to use `fclose` with the correct file ID.

```
fid = open('test.txt');
fprintf(fid,'This is a test.\n');
fclose(fid);
fid = 0; % Optional, this will make it clear that the file is not open,
         % but it is not necessary since matlab will send a not open message anyway
```

Regarding the function creation the syntax is something like this:

```
function out = myFcn(x,y)
z = x*y;
fprintf('z=%.0f\n',z); % Print value of z in the command window
out = z>0;
```

This is a function that checks if two numbers are positive and returns true they are. If not it returns false. This may not be the best way to do this test, but it works as example I guess.

Please comment if this is not what you want to know.